# XSLT output contains unwanted data between

Tags: xslt

I am trying to create a xslt to transform xml to ttl (turtle rdf).
Unfortunately, I am getting some unwanted data between my templates and I do not know xslt well enough to understand why.

Any ideas why I am getting data between every template match?  It is clear that there is something going on between the templates.    Thank you!  John

Comment: What would be the desired output ?

Comment: I suggest you post a minimal, **reproducible** example of code (XML+XSLT). As a guess: read up on built-in template rules http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt/#built-in-rule

Comment: OK, you've got a program that takes some input and produces some output and it's not the output you want, and you want us to debug it for you without seeing the program, the input, the output, or the desired output? Dream on.

Comment: You are right, Michael Kay.  I had posted some fragments because the actual files were too big.  I followed the hint by Michael.hor and found answer to my own question.  Apologies for the confusion.  John

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Michael.
The answer can be found in post entitled: "Why does XSLT output all text by default?"
Basically, there were elements that my xslt was not matching, and by default, those are written to the output due to the built-in template rules.  John